# Evaluate $\sum\frac{1}{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is $\sum\frac{1}{n^n}$??  I know it is $\int{x^x}dx$ but how? And what is $\int{x^x}dx$??

My approach to solve $\int{x^x}dx$:-
$x^x=e^{x\ln{x}}$  integrate this and use maccaularine series. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

See [Sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) on Wikipedia.